# ARRAYFORMULA not adding to each row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

When I add formula to the top of the cell `W2`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(if(and(T2:T="",Q2:Q<>""),"VALID","")))
```

It works fine on that row, however the 2nd row has the same conditions, but it does not say `VALID` like the 1st row does.  When I copy that formula to the 2nd row it shows `VALID`... So the formula is working, it is not copying down automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use the `ARRAYFORMULA` function you should use `*` instead of the `AND` function.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(IF((T2:T="")*(Q2:Q<>""),"VALID","")))
```